# Is it possible to save intermediate Spark DataFrames to disk without significantly affecting performance?

Tags: performance, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, pipeline

Let's suppose I have the following data pipeline:

[image: data pipeline]

`Companies` and `Shuttles` are my input datasets read from disk using Spark, the `preprocess_*` functions perform some heavy data cleaning operations, and `create_master_table_node` is another function that takes 3 Spark `DataFrame`s as input.

Generally, my understanding is that it's most performant to not write any of the intermediate Spark `DataFrame`s (i.e. `Preprocessed Companies`, `Preprocessed Shuttles`) to disk. https://spokeo-engineering.medium.com/whats-the-fastest-way-to-store-intermediate-results-in-spark-54f2080defb6 suggests the same.

However, there are also benefits to persisting intermediate data to disk, such as being able to resume failed workflows or analyze intermediate results post-hoc. These benefits are important to me, so I want the intermediate outputs persisted at some point in my workflow--be it just after they're computed or one the entirely pipeline finishes or errors out. What's the least performance-impacting way to save `Preprocessed Companies`, `Preprocessed Shuttles`, etc. to disk? Is there a way to do this without affecting the rest of the computational graph?

Comment: Dataframe is based on RDD (resilient distributed data) so going something wrong at runtime is very less likely. I don't agree with the author of using cache to save it temporary. cache should be used when you are planning to use same dataframe at multiple places.

Comment: @GaurangShah agree with you..if instantiation of execution of  pipeline once a day..instead of caching checkpoint will be good in this case.